# jQuery Image load() event return false not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write a function for checking image height and width. You can find my code below. It works but I have a problem with `return false`: it does not work.

```
$("#published").click(function( event ){
    var img = $('<img src="'+selectedImage+'"/>').load(function( event  ){
                  var orgWidth = this.width;
                  var orgHeight = this.height;
                  console.log(orgWidth+" = "+orgHeight);

                  if(orgWidth >= 169 && orgHeight >= 169){
                    thisValidate.parent('div.rwmb-input').children('.imageError').remove();
                    return true;
                  }else{
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if(thisValidate.parent('div.rwmb-input').children('.imageError').length == 0){
                      thisValidate.parent('div.rwmb-input').append("<p class='imageError'></p>");
                    }
                    thisValidate.parent('div.rwmb-input').children('.imageError').html('<br/><label for="techranger_booked_feature_images" class="error">Upload Image More then 169 x 169</label>');
                    return false;
                  }
              });

});
```

I have added `event.preventDefault();` but it did not help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning to the `load()` function which isn't going to return to the outer click function.

Also `load()` is asynchronous so the click event will be completed long before `load()`.

Finally you have 2 `event` arguments and the one inside `load` isn't going to have any impact on the click

You would need to prevent the click completely and trigger the next event manually when the `load()` succeeds.

```
$("#published").click(function( event ){
     event.preventDefault();// prevent default
    // no access to "this" inside load() so store reference to form
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');

    var img = $('<img src="'+selectedImage+'"/>').load(function(imgEvt ){
           // code removed for clarity
          if(orgWidth >= 169 && orgHeight >= 169){
               /* trigger form submit */
               $form.submit();
          }else{
             // other code
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: i don't have form. I working with third party form thanks for your Answer

Comment: OK then what does the click do? You have to intercept it to do what you are wanting or check the image elesewhere

Comment: i get click event of submit button lik `$("input[type='submit']").click(function(){ //code  })`

Comment: OK... so it doesn't matter if form is 3rd party unless there is also 3rd party event handler on button as well

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `return false` is running in the scope of the function which serves the `load` event and your `event` is an event of `jQuery` `load` function.

Secondly, if you want to do it on the button, you cannot do it synchronously like you try to do because the request to get your image is asynchronous, so it happens *after* your function on button event is finished (so you can't stop the event default behavior because it is already happened). You are forced to prevent / return false in the `click` method regardless of the image size and then call another function when the check is (un-?)successful to go on. This is the only way.

```
$("#published").click(function(event){
  // here your check, e.g. if (imageFits) goOnFunction();

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

And finally you [absolutely do not need jQuery here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image):

```
var myImage = new Image();

myImage.src = 'http://okolo.me/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/5998.jpg';

myImage.onload = function() {
    // here you can use myImage.width and myImage.height
};
```